# Internally how does JavaScript iterate over object keys?

Tags: javascript, object, iterator, hashmap, v8

In JavaScript, when we use the `for...in` loop or the `Object.keys()` method, how does the internal engine iterate over the object keys?

I know this might slightly change from one implementation to another, but I'm sure there's a general approach, could you give a bird's-eye overview?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? Are you asking about the order? I would think the "how" would be entirely implementation dependant and not terribly useful information in a JS program.

Comment: I don't mean the order, I mean how it's done. And whether it's useful to know or not, that's a personal opinion: let's stick to the question.

Comment: Do you mean the implementation of every browser and how they would interpret javascript code or do you want something like the ECMA specification? Something like this? http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach

Comment: It's not an opinion. If you need to iterate, you need to iterate. Implementation details don't matter. If you meant to compare `for-in` vs `Object.keys() + for`, that's a little different but implementation details still don't matter. What would matter would be laying out your concerns and comparing the two.

Comment: @DuKes0mE, I mean an overview how it is conceptually done, in layman's terms.

Comment: @LyeFish the question is about implementation architecture, not performance comparison. If you're not interested it's ok.

Comment: I understand what it's about, which is why I said it's not useful information in a program. What you seem to have is a programmer's curiosity rather than a specific programming problem. Still, your question is far too broad as implementations can differ radically, not just slightly. The concept is laid out in the specification but implementations only need to make it *appear* as though the steps in the spec are followed.

Comment: @LyeFish, I hope you agree that the concept of "useful" is subjective, thanks. I could describe to you how this question is related to a specific programming problem, but – trust me – it would take a long time and it still wouldn't change the original question.

Comment: Given a task that needs to be performed which requires enumeration of object keys, then it's really not all that subjective... unless you're going to abandon the project altogether based on the details of some specific implementation. I'd encourage you to describe the specific situation in your question. You may be making assumptions that don't reflect reality. Reading some of your comments on your earlier question, you seem to assume that strings are passed by value. This generally isn't the case.

Comment: @LyeFish your latest point seems off-topic, but I'd like to understand more about it. In JS if you type `var a = 'first';`, then `var b = a;`, then `a = 'second';`, then `console.log(a); // returns -> "second"`, and `console.log(b);  // returns -> "first"`. Although the implementation background is a bit more complex, couldn't we consider this "passing by value"?

Comment: My last point was an example of an assumption. I don't know if it relates to your problem because I don't know the problem. I only noticed in under a question you asked a little while ago. But my point was that the string data itself isn't by value, but instead it's similar to the way objects are passed by value in that you don't get a copy of the object, but rather a copy of a reference to the object. So while it's still passing "by value", the cost of passing a 3 character string is generally the same as that of a 3,000 character string because only the reference is copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's less about how object.keys works and more about how an object's properties are represented. In V8 there is in-object properties (same representation as  C struct fields or Java object fields), fixed out-of-object properties stored in a fixed array and dynamic out-of-object properties stored in a hash table.

The layout of the in-object properties and the fixed out-of-object properties is stored separately in the object's hidden class. If the object's layout changes it gets a new hidden class. Like a [Java's Class object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()), the hidden class object contains the names of the fixed properties and you simply iterate over that array.

When using hash table (aka dictionary, hashmap or normalized object) representation you must dynamically iterate over the hash table keys just like you iterate over any hash table.